# Is it safe to pass NSManagedObjectID-s between multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator-s?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I have multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instances that have just one NSPersistentStore each, all pointing to the same sqlite file. And in my testing passing NSManagedObjectID objects between them, and then calling

> `- (NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID
>   *)objectID error:(NSError **)error`

on NSManagedObjectContext seems to work fine, but I have yet to come across any documentation from apple that confirms that this is supposed to work fine.

So, my question is, if anyone knows if this is supposed to work (a link to some apple documentation confirming it would be awesome!), of if anybody knows that this is not usually supposed to work, and that I should not be doing this, that would be awesome too!

Comment: From testing I've done in the past (pre-iOS7) there were issues where fetching objects using a "SELF IN ..." predicate returned no results when using IDs from different stores (had to pass through URI representation first to work). other than that, all other operations seemed to work fine.

Comment: @DanShelly Sound fair, I was originally passing around URI Representations, but out of curiosity/for exercise, decided try object IDs, though I'm not using those object IDs in fetch requests, just calling existingObjectWithID:error: using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always safe to call that method. Whether it returns an object is another story.

When using an object ID from a different context, you'll only get a non-nil result if the object is already accessible to the context you call this method on. That implies that the object already exists in the persistent store, meaning it has already been saved on its original managed object context.

Or in other words, you'll only get a non-nil result if you've already saved the object with the ID, and if you're using the object's permanent (post-save) ID.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I've mostly been taking all the usual precautions, if I'm passing the object ID of an object that hasn't been saved, I call obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error: and have not run into any issues so far. Do you think it is safe to pass object IDs between different coordinators which have one store each pointing to the same sqlite file? or should I really be passing around URI representations?

Comment: Passing around object IDs is fine-- that's the whole reason they're exposed via public API. Getting permanent IDs like that might still get nil results in other coordinators, because they can only look up the object by going to the persistent store file. If you haven't actually save the object, it might not be accessible to other coordinators yet.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll make additions to my code to check for temporary IDs before passing them, and nil managed objects after retrieving them (I'm already checking for the error on obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:), to be on the safe side. Thank you, kind sir!